# My Sessions Keeps Sending a Fixed Value while it's supposed to be changeable

Tags: php, html

Well i got this script

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION["sup"] = $row['id']; 
        if ($hi <  $row['buytime']) {

        } else {

           echo " <form action='Action1.php' method='get'>
                Thanks for buying from our shop , if the item with id <input type='submit' value='" . $row['id'] ."' class='btn-link'/>  </form>";

           echo "<form action='Action.php' method='post'>
                 is a bad tool , you can report by clicking on the following button <input  type='submit' value='Report Item' />
                 </form>";
        }
}
```

The only problem is hat in line             `$_SESSION["sup"] = $row['id'];`
Keeps sending a fixed value which it's 144 while  the $row['id']; is not a fixed value , i'm really lost lol

If session is a bad idea , how can i send ID to action.php without inserting the ID in a hidden input ?

Update the two pages

```
First PAge  



 <?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "localhost", "localhost", "localhost");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$buyer      = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql_shells = "SELECT buytime,id,situation,buyer FROM shells WHERE situation = 'sold' AND buyer = '$buyer'  ";
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->modify('+172799 seconds');
$hi = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$_SESSION["sup"] = [];

$result = $conn->query($sql_shells);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $_SESSION["sup"][] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION["sup"] = implode(',', $session['sup']);  // use this var

if ($hi <  $row['buytime']) {

         }else{

  echo " <form action='view_item.php' method='get'>
  Thanks for buying from our shop , if the item with id <input type='submit' value='" . $row['id'] ."' class='btn-link'/>  </form>";

  echo "<form action='reportinsert.php' method='post'>
  is a bad tool , you can report by clicking on the following button <input  type='submit' value='Report Item' />
       </form>";
 }
  }
  }else {

    }

    ?>
```

**Second page**

```
     <?php
   session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {


 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "localhost", "localhost", "localhost");

 if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

   $seller = $_SESSION['username']; 
 $id = $_POST['whatever'];
 $id = explode(',', $id); // You now have an array of IDs.
 $sql = "INSERT INTO reports (reporter,stats,trn_date,itemid) VALUES ('$seller','Opened','$trn_date','$id')";
 if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
 echo $id;
 echo $seller;
 } else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
 }

 } else
  {
header("location:/quickshops/login.php");
 }
 ?>
```

now it gives me Array in insert

Comment: `$_SESSION["sup"]` will be the _last_ value of the rows, because you overwrite it.

Comment: and how to fix it , i mean use correctly it , because i had         ` $_SESSION["param"] = $row["id"]; ` in another page and it changes depend the ids ,

Comment: What are you expecting `$_SESSION["sup"]` to be? An array of all the ids?

Comment: yes , it worked in another page .

Comment: If you are trying to match every form with its ID for every row, without putting it into a the form in the HTML itself, then that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting the value every time you go through the loop:

```
 // loop through results
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // overwrite session variable with the last id
        $_SESSION["sup"] = $row['id'];
```

So if you have 10 results, the session var will be the id of the 10th row.

Without more detail on what you are trying to achieve with your result set, we can't really help much more than that. Maybe update your question with more details if this isn't enough to solvce your problem?

> Update Ok so you need ALL Id's

You could make the session var an array, and when it's time to post the ID's, `implode()` them with a comma. Then in the receiving script, explode on a comma to get all the ids.

```
 $_SESSION["sup"] = [];
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $_SESSION["sup"][] = $row['id'];
    // etc
 }
 $_SESSION["sup"] = implode(',', $session['sup']); // use this var
```

And in the other script

```
$ids = $_POST['whatever'];
$ids = explode(',', $ids); // You now have an array of IDs.
```

Incidentally, since you are using a session variable, you probably don't even need to post it, and just access the session in the other script, but then I've no idea what your code is doing

Comment: You have an array of rows. Which row should you be using? And why have you many rows to start with?

Comment: Do you want ALL of the ids?

Comment: Yes i want to send all the ids from page (index.php) to action.php without involving it in a hidden input

Comment: input type is a different concern. Why not concatenate the id's with a comma? I'll update my answer with this suggestion

Comment: Okey sir i be waiting

Comment: it says unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in    $ids = implode(',', $session['sup']; // use this var

Comment: argh crap i missed an apostrophe you can see where it breaks! Let me update it

Comment: and a bracket at the end of the implode line! try it now!

Comment: the fixed ID became Array instaed

Comment: correct, you now have an array of ID,s. Loop through and deal with each now! :-)

Comment: then you are sending the session array and not the imploded `$ids` variable we just created. Make sure you send the string and not the array

Comment: i doubt that tbh. maybe there are lots. Unless you haven't described what you want correctly, this is the solution

Comment: What is `$result` the result of?

Comment: users insert the ids that's why , so is this the right scripT ? even could not find how to Fix why it keeps Inserting Array word instead of ids

Comment: $result = $conn->query($sql_shells);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

Comment: that doesnt help, i was hoping to see the query. Regardless, try this line `$_SESSION["sup"] = implode(',', $session['sup']);` see updated answer

Comment: Sir lol same issue , look i did put the 2 pages here can you pleaase take a look ? thanks af for helping https://pastebin.com/KuCGfjYZ

Comment: pastebin is blocked in this office

Answer (score 0):

You will always get the last row's value, the reason is, you set the session in each iteration so whenever you plan to use it out of the loop, you will get the value of last iteration.

In case you want to set the array within the session, that's how you can do that:

```
$idsArray= array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $idsArray[] = $row['id']; 
}

$_SESSION["ids"]  =  $idsArray;
```

Comment: Sir how it's possible to fix it

Comment: what do you want to fix? what value to do you need in session? you statement is not clear enought

Comment: What i'm trying to do , is to send the Ids from the current page to action.php page (inserting page ) without involving it in a hidden input

Comment: why don't you set the array within the session?

Comment: how can i do it , ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, just get the value from session and get the array of ids

Comment: always same isssue :/

Comment: are you doing it the way I showed? does your result set have unique ids or it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Remove inside $row '' from $row['id'].